# How can I sort column in child component clicking on heading in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

The problem is I don't know how to put effect from parent component to child component...
I'm creating sorting function.

```
tableSort = (event, sortKey) => {
        const {data} = this.state;
        data.sort((a,b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]) )
        this.setState({ data })
    }
```

and then I'm trying to render that in my table

```
render() {
    const {data} = this.state
    return (
        <>
            <Table>
                <Thead>
                    <Tr>
                        <Th onClick={e => this.tableSort(e, 'pool number')}>Pool Number</Th>
                        <Th>Sender</Th>
                        <Th>Not Routed Reason</Th>
                        <Th>Sent Date Time</Th>
                        <Th>Requested Delivery Report Mask Text</Th>
                        <Th>Delivery Report Received Date Time</Th>
                        <Th>isUnicode</Th>
                        <Th>MessageUUID</Th>
                    </Tr>
                </Thead>
                {this.renderData(data)}
            </Table>
        </>
    )
}
```

The child component is called in this component and it locks like this..

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tbody, Tr, Td } from 'react-super-responsive-table'

const TablePageList = ({data}) => {
    const {poolNumber, sender, notRoutedReason, sentDateTime, requestedDeliveryReportMaskText,
        deliveryReportReceivedDateTime, isUnicode, messageUUID} = data
        return (
            <Tbody>
                <Tr>
                    <Td>{poolNumber}</Td>
                    <Td>{sender}</Td>
                    <Td>{notRoutedReason}</Td>
                    <Td>{sentDateTime}</Td>
                    <Td>{requestedDeliveryReportMaskText}</Td>
                    <Td>{deliveryReportReceivedDateTime}</Td>
                    <Td>{isUnicode}</Td>
                    <Td>{messageUUID}</Td>
                </Tr>
            </Tbody>
        )
    }

export default TablePageList
```

So how can I access and sort my Td from Th?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the child component from parent. You didn't call any child component.

Try below code.

import child compenent url.

```
import TablePageList from "./TablePageList";
```

And then keep state data.

```
 this.state = {
   data:[]
 }
```

Also change function `setState` and `order data`.

```
tableSort = (event, sortKey) => {
  const {data} = this.state;
  data.sort((a,b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]) )
  this.setState({ data: data })
}
```

And call `TablePageList` component below `</Thead>`

```
render() {
const { data } = this.state;
return (
    <Table>
      <Thead>
        <Tr>
          <Th onClick={e => this.tableSort(e, "pool number")}>
            Pool Number
          </Th>
          <Th>Sender</Th>
          <Th>Not Routed Reason</Th>
          <Th>Sent Date Time</Th>
          <Th>Requested Delivery Report Mask Text</Th>
          <Th>Delivery Report Received Date Time</Th>
          <Th>isUnicode</Th>
          <Th>MessageUUID</Th>
        </Tr>
      </Thead>
      {data.map(element => {
        <TablePageList data={element}></TablePageList>;
      })}
    </Table>
);
```

}

And then you get `data` and fill it.

```
const TablePageList = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Tbody>
      <Tr>
        <Td>{data.poolNumber}</Td>
        <Td>{data.sender}</Td>
        <Td>{data.notRoutedReason}</Td>
        <Td>{data.sentDateTime}</Td>
        <Td>{data.requestedDeliveryReportMaskText}</Td>
        <Td>{data.deliveryReportReceivedDateTime}</Td>
        <Td>{data.isUnicode}</Td>
        <Td>{data.messageUUID}</Td>
      </Tr>
    </Tbody>
  );
};
```

Comment: The thing is, I did it all even I didn't write code here... I did it sam as you wrote, even simpler, but I'm just interested, how can I take value from the child, since I need to sort that values... my sortKey is undefined because I don't know how to pull that value from the child component...